# How i can get JSON data from this URL?

Tags: php, json

I have a URL that returns a JSON object like this:

```
{"ip":"192.168.48.68"}
```

I want to get the `ip` value. So how can I retrieve it through PHP?

Answer (score 2):

use the `json_decode` method:

```
$json = YOUR_JSON_OBJECT;
$ip = json_decode($json, true);
//then you can get the ip using its index in the array
$ip["ip"] //192.168.48.68
```